# CSS - How to set many div width with a non-round percentage to fill a parent div space

Tags: css, html, size, width

I have a div that has a variable width.
It contains 6 divs that should have the same width.
All those 6 div, put side-by-side may fill the entiere space of the parent div.

How may I set the child div width in CSS so I'm sure there will be not gap between the child borders and the parent one.

I've tried many values but depending of the size of the parent div, sometimes I have a gap at the right side, sometimes it exceed the limits of the parent div, sometimes it's ok. Trying for now 16%, 17%, 16.6%, 16.51%, 16.67%

How this should be made in CSS ?

Comment: To fill up the whole width, your percentages need to add up to 100% if you are restricting the width of every child element. Is that your question, or am I missing something?

Comment: @thatidiotguy:yes, but 100/6 gives 16.66666. Depending on the size of the parent div, even when using 16.6, I have sometimes the 6 boxes that takes more that the parent's width size. So I'd like to know how can I reach 100% when I cannot have a round result when dividing 100 by the number of boxes, or even being able to fill correctly the parent's width when using the nearest decimal result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76C4B/)

Learn about Flex display

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Is the best way to stop doing calculations it always fit in the grid

HTML

```
<div>
    <p class="p1">1</p>
    <p class="p1">2</p>
    <p class="p1">3</p>
    <p class="p1">4</p>
    <p class="p1">5</p>
    <p class="p1">6</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="p1">1</p>
    <p class="p1">1</p>
    <p class="p1">1</p>
    <p class="p1">1</p>
    <p class="p2">2</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display:-moz-box;
    /* Firefox */
    display:-webkit-box;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    display:box;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.p1 {
    -moz-box-flex:1.0;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-flex:1.0;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -ms-flex:1.0;
    /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    box-flex:1.0;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.p2 {
    -moz-box-flex:2.0;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-flex:2.0;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -ms-flex:2.0;
    /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    box-flex:2.0;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Know your audience though; flexbox support in some browsers isn't great yet. Caniuse.com is a great reference to check that sort of thing.

Comment: I used your idea to set a different percentage to the last item, so it's visually near the same as the others, but at the end it's 100% of the width.